# External HD Sleeping on Windows 10

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, external-hard-drive, sleep

I have an external SSD HD (Kingston HD with an Orico USB3 enclosure) that seems to fall asleep after 15 minutes of being idle.

I've checked all my power settings for USB and for Hard drives to never fall asleep, but still encounter the problem. Only solution currently is to unplug the cable and plug it back in.

I've come across the KeepAliveHD app, but was wondering if there was a better alternative?

Comment: It could be a function of the firmware of the enclosures usb chip.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this on win 10 with a video wall installation where the driver for the IR touch overlay would unload after 15 minutes. The solution was logging into windows services as an elevated user/administrator, then an extra tab shows up in the driver configuration that will allow you to keep it from going to sleep.